# What does this `xhost ...` command do?

Tags: x11, x-server, xhost

Please help me understand this line of command:

```
xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm
```

in [reference to the answer in this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/455857) and also suggest if there's a better way and why that's needed. I couldn't make much from the man page, so I expect some more detailed answer to make it simple. (Should I replace localuser with my username, and is it something like adding to the group? I get that + is for adding but don't understand SI or si !)

Please also mention how is the user added to the *"list allowed to make connections"* and what that means. Also, how I check the current list?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`xhost +SI:localuser:lightdm` allows the `lightdm` user to access the running X server. The current X server is indicated by the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

---

The [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/xhost.1) has reasonably good explanations:

```
   [+]name The given name (the plus sign is optional) is added to the list
           allowed to connect to the X server.  The name  can  be  a  host
           name or a complete name (See NAMES for more details).
...
NAMES
   A complete name has the syntax ``family:name'' where the  families  are
   as follows:
...
   si        Server Interpreted
...
   the server interpreted address "si:localuser:username" can be  used  to
   specify a single local user. (See the Xsecurity(7) manual page for more
   details.)
```

And the [`Xsecurity` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/Xsecurity.7) says:

```
SERVER INTERPRETED ACCESS TYPES
   The  sample  implementation   includes   several   Server   Interpreted
   mechanisms:
       IPv6                          IPv6 literal addresses
       hostname                      Network host name
       localuser                     Local connection user id
       localgroup                    Local connection group id
```

With a bit of context: There are two commonly used ways to allow access to an X server. One is via an `Xauthority` file, which is shared by the clients, and needs no further server-side configuration. The other is via the `xhost` list, where configuration is done on the server at *runtime* (so this is not a permanent change).

So, `localuser` is a keyword to be retained as is (`lightdm` is the username here, the one that LightDM runs as). This is somewhat like adding to a group, in that the groups are in the server's understanding of authorization. However, no system groups or users are affected. Only the X server's runtime configuration is changed.

The default behaviour of `xhost` when run without arguments is to print the list, as the manpage says:

```
nothing If no command line arguments are given,  a  message  indicating
        whether  or not access control is currently enabled is printed,
        followed by the list of those allowed to connect.
```

For example:

```
$ xhost
access control enabled, only authorized clients can connect
SI:localuser:muru
```

We'll probably need to examine code to determine *how* a user is added to the list, and how X uses that list.

---

The reason this is done is to use `gsettings`, which uses `dbus`, which in turn usually needs an X server running.  However, this is not necessary, and you could see [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276509/change-gsettings-without-running-x-and-unity).

Comment: This is a really good answer; I'm interested in how to persist the `host +xxx` or `host -zzz` settings too.

Comment: When I run `xhost` without arguments it hangs, it is a normal behavior? @muru

Comment: @will I didn't try personally, but editing `~/.xprofile` with the adequate `xhost` commands would likely give you persistence.

Comment: @muru Concerning how the X server enforces `SI:localuser:<user>` directives, the only reasonable way I see is to check what process is requesting access through its UNIX socket, and checking if the process' UID (RUID or EUID, I don't know) corresponds to the authorised user. That sort of information is usually available on non security-hardened systems. Check `ss`, the socket statistics tool. One common path name for X server UNIX sockets on display zero is `/tmp/.X11-unix/X0`.