# Distinguishing between running a process in client terminal or on the server when using SSH

Tags: ssh, x11, display

I was trying to play a video on my laptop using SSH command from my android phone(JuiceSSH). but the video started playing in bytes in my phone's terminal. the player was VLC player. how can I make it run the movie on the laptop not on my phone terminal.

Comment: Is there someone logged in on the laptop's console?

Comment: @Celada yes. does it make any differences?

Comment: Makes it easier, especially if it's the *same* user logged in to the console and logging in by SSH. Therefore I thought it would be relevant info to include in your question. But it looks like you got an answer so it's all good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VLC` would be using the X Window System for the pictures.  If you have a session running on the laptop, e.g., its *desktop*, X would be running.

From the desktop you can make a connection to X without problem, and use [`xhost`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xhost.1.html) to add your phone to the "computers" which can connect to the X display.  Something like this (in a terminal on the laptop):

```
xhost +myphone
```

where *myphone* is the hostname of your phone.  Then in the phone, you would set the `DISPLAY` variable (if VLC has no suitable command-line option) to point to that X display, e.g,

```
export DISPLAY=mylaptop
vlc
```

In the `DISPLAY` variable, you have to use the screen number (usually 0 for the actual computer), e.g., "mylaptop:0".

Further reading:

- [What does this `xhost …` command do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177557/what-does-this-xhost-command-do)
- [Xhost](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xhost) (Arch wiki)

Comment: works like a chump!!! Thank you so much. very usefull.

Comment: Uh? The video is being played by a process running on the laptop, to display on the laptop. `xhost` is useless and dangerous.

Comment: I explictly pointed to opening up the specific hostname, as well as providing suitable reading to cover the problems with the approach.  Everyone knows about `xhost +`; it seems that some people never noticed the "+".