# gksudo --user postgres pgadmin3 produces Unable to initialize GTK+. Why?

Tags: gtk

```
$ pgadmin3
$ pcmanfm 
$ gksudo pcmanfm
```

Invoke the programs fine but:

```
$ gksudo --user postgres pgadmin3
```

Produces:

```
19:38:10: Error: Unable to initialize GTK+, is DISPLAY set properly?
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, another user does not have permission to use the X screen.

This works for me:

```
xhost SI:localuser:postgres

gksudo --user postgres pgadmin3

# or sudo -u postgres -H pgadmin3
```

Related answer: [What does this `xhost ...` command do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177557/)