# How to connect to a xserver from my system-wide terminal?

Tags: tmux, raspbian, gui, openbox, x-server

I am currently trying to make an autonomous drone using the Robot Operating System ([ROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System)). To do this, I have installed **Raspbian Lite** (**Jessie**) on a **Rasperry Pi 3** and am currently using **ROS Kinetic** on it. Because it is **Raspbian Lite**, there were no window managers or desktop environments that came along with the installation. I decided to go with **Openbox Window Manager** and installed a terminal onto it for convenience. I can just call `sudo startx`, and the window manager opens up, which can be accesed by `Ctrl + alt + F2`. Since it is a system-wide terminal, I have also installed **tmux** for convenience. I am running the xserver on a particular pane and conduct my ROS work on other panes.

Now when I try to run commands that call on a GUI application from my system-wide terminal, I get the error:

```
QxcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted
```

Now there are two ways to approach this problem:

1. Since there is a terminal installed in my Window Manager, I should get ROS working on this? However, I do not know how to change the environment of the terminal emulator inside the window manager so that it is the same as the one on the system-wide terminal. Is it as easy as changing shells?
2. Actually find a way to send my GUI applications to the tmux pane that is currently running the command `sudo startx`. How do I switch the parent of a process with another parent?

---

**NOTE**: *I definitely would prefer the second solution, as it is more elegant and efficient for my workflow.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a terminal in your GUI environment, type:

```
xhost +
```

In the non-GUI environment, type:

```
export DISPLAY="localhost:0"
```

Then, graphical applications that you launch from the non-GUI environment will be displayed in the GUI environment.

You can read more in `man xhost`

See also this answer from: [What does this `xhost …` command do?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177566/90691)

Comment: I have added the problems I am having with this as a [separate question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333739/how-do-i-use-xhost-for-this-situation). Please take a look into it?