# How do I use xhost for this situation?

Tags: xorg, raspbian, openbox, x-server, xhost

I am currently trying to make an autonomous drone using the Robot Operating System ([ROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System)). To do this, I have installed **Raspbian Lite** (**Jessie**) on a **Rasperry Pi 3** and am currently using **ROS Kinetic** on it. I decided to go with **Openbox Window Manager** and installed a terminal onto it for convenience. I can just call `sudo startx`. Since it is a system-wide terminal, I have also installed **tmux** for convenience. I am running the xserver on a particular pane and conduct my ROS work on other panes.

Now when I try to run commands that call on a GUI application from my system-wide terminal, I get the error:

```
QxcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted
```

After a recommendation from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333046/how-to-connect-to-a-xserver-from-my-system-wide-terminal) question, I decided to install `xhost` on my terminal emulator. After invoking `xhost +` in the same emulator, I get this:

```
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
```

After which I invoke xhost which returns with:

```
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
SI:localuser:root
```

Therefore, within my system-wide terminal, I have set the environmental variable to 5 different values which have been listed below, and tried to run the program which calls on the `$DISPLAY`, but I get the same `QxcbConnection: Could not connect to display` error.

```
SI:localuser:root 
localuser:root 
localuser 
root 
SI:localuser
localhost:0
```

The last one was actually from the linked question. To my understanding, I am doing exactly what is listed out in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/xhost-1.html) man page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the terminal emulator (the one where you ran `xhost +`), what is the output of `echo $DISPLAY` ?

Comment: @JigglyNaga it says `:0`

Comment: @JigglyNaga What should I use as the $DISPLAY on my first virtual terminal device?

Comment: The same.  `export DISPLAY=:0`

Comment: @JigglyNaga Just tried it, and got the error: 

`QxcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted`

Comment: What GUI command are you trying to run?  Do you get the same when starting another X client eg. `xterm`?

Comment: I'm not trying to invoke a specific GUI command. I am trying tto however, call upon an application that uses GUI. I don't know what GUI command the application would run. What do you mean by starting another X client like `xterm` though?

Comment: @JigglyNaga I have posted a new question that better explains my problem. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @ I can close this question, once you have had a look at that question.

Comment: When you say you "call an application that uses GUI", what exactly are you doing?  What steps are involved in this "call"?  If you don't invoke a command, what *do* you do just before this error message appears?

Comment: @JigglyNaga `rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node` is the exact thing I am calling. rosrun is a function that runs a particular node in the ros environment, to my understanding. `turtlesim` is the name of the library and `turtlesim_node` is the specific node from that library that is being called. `turtlesim_node` calls on a GUI window to display the movement of a turtle. If you would like to know more, please take a look at [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes) guide.

Comment: @JigglyNaga In terms of the steps, I have `ROS` installed on my *Rpi* and I run `roscore`.

Comment: Please can you try running `xterm`, or any other simple X11 application (eg. `lxterminal` - I don't know what else you've got installed), from the same prompt where you're trying to use `rosrun`?  If that works, and the new xterm appears in the already-running X session, then you've correctly set up `xhost`, and we can start worrying about ROS.

Comment: @JigglyNaga let me try that

Comment: @JigglyNaga none of the other x11 applications work either

Comment: What error do you get from other x11 apps when they fail?   Please [edit the question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/333739/edit) to show the exact command you ran, and the complete error message that it produced.  That will make it easier for others to reproduce your problem.