# How do I use xhost for linking the display of one virtual terminal device to another?

Tags: xorg, virtual-machine, openbox, x-server, xhost

I am currently trying to make an autonomous drone using the Robot Operating System ([ROS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_Operating_System)). To do this, I have installed **Raspbian Lite** (**Jessie**) on a **Rasperry Pi 3** and am currently using **ROS Kinetic** on it. I decided to go with **Openbox Window Manager** and installed a terminal onto it for convenience. I can just call `sudo startx` to open up a window manager in another terminal. Since there is no desktop environment, I have also installed **tmux** for convenience. I am running the *xserver* on a particular pane and conduct my *ROS* work on other panes.

Now when I try to run commands that call on a GUI application from my first terminal virtual device (`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1`), I get the error:

```
QxcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Aborted
```

After a recommendation from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333046/how-to-connect-to-a-xserver-from-my-system-wide-terminal) question, I decided to install `xhost` on my terminal emulator (which is running on my window manager on my second terminal virtual device, that can be accessed by `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F2`). After invoking `xhost +` in the same emulator, I get this:

```
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
```

After which I invoke `xhost` which returns with:

```
access control disabled, clients can connect from any host
SI:localuser:root
```

Therefore, in my first virtual terminal device, I have set the environmental variable to 5 different values which have been listed below, and tried to run the program which calls on the `$DISPLAY`, but I get the same `QxcbConnection: Could not connect to display` error.

```
SI:localuser:root 
localuser:root 
localuser 
root 
SI:localuser
localhost:0
```

The last one was actually from the linked question. To my understanding, I am doing exactly what is listed out in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/xhost-1.html) man page. What am I doing wrong?

---

**NOTE**

I have also tried `ssh`'ing into the window manager with `ssh root@raspberrypi` (which is what I infer the user@hostname to be from the prompt in my terminal emulator inside my window manager). However, this asks me for a password, which I do not know and cannot access. This is the topic for [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334752/how-to-ssh-into-a-separate-virtual-terminal-within-the-same-device) question.